# correctly import files from index.html with webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

how can i correctly import files to my project from index.html file,exactly like what webpack does for create-react-app apps,like below:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

> i want to use something like %PUBLIC% in my project and i am as dumb as the orange man, so please answer in specific details and/or with an example or a good documentation link

Comment: if its a js file you can use script tag.

Comment: @SachinKammar no i cant,i want to import local files using index.html,and only with webpack,simple ./a.js or /a.js doesnt work

Comment: in your head tag add script e.g: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> it works

Comment: @SachinKammar local files

Comment: add those files to your public directory. for e.g if you have a scrpit.js file in public folder. you can import it as <script src="/script.js"></script>

Comment: @SachinKammar thanks,it doesnt work with webpack,and as i said,i want to know what create-react-app does and do the same for my project

Comment: @MohsenParvar I believe that the browser itself is responsible for evaluating and retrieving what is inside the `href=""`. This means that as Sachin said, you only need to put `href="/favicon.ico"` in there and your web browser will automatically put in the URL and download it. You aren't including any files, you are telling the browser where to get them.